# Select records integer between two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return all records for a range plus specific range agree a value (integer), but not work as I need...

I created a table with values and part of this must return in all cases, and part of records only if between a value.

I created a fiddle to explore it

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43d802/1

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (
    nump INT NULL,
    vmin INT DEFAULT 1 NULL,
    vmax INT DEFAULT 999999 NULL
);

INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(1, 1, 999999);
INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(2, 1, 999999);
INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(3, 1, 999999);
INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(4, 400, 499);
INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(5, 500, 599);
INSERT INTO newtable (nump, vmin, vmax) VALUES(6, 600, 999999);

Select * from newtable
where ((vmin = 1 and vmax = 999999) or 
       (vmin > 1 and vmax <= 408));
```

Comment: Your fiddle has no rows with `vmax <= 408`.

Comment: What result are you expecting from this?

Comment: Change 408 to 508 and you'll get additional results.

Comment: I think I see the problem.  You have a solution with no requirement.

Comment: @Barmar yes, the range 400 to 499 cover the 408 situation. The result expect is get rows from generic situations (min = 1 and max = 999999) , specific ranges (between the number) and max limit (for example last row , when applicable).

Comment: @dougp my requirement is get generic rows plus specific ranges, but some ranges can be higher than current range . For example if I search for 715 I need to return all rows, but if I search for 515 I need to return 1 to 5

Comment: It sounds like you should be testing `vmin  < 408`, not `vmax < 408`.

Comment: So it should be `vmin BETWEEN 2 AND 407`

Comment: If I put a between, like 407 for example, I return this row, but the row with 300 is ignored. Check this fiddle please, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ee9e/3, you'll see 4th row is ignored, but I need it on return (200 range)

Comment: I explained better the results there I have and what I expect http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ee9e/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but I guess that 408 is your data to test, and U want to get the records with no max ( 1,2,3 ) and the record #4.

```
declare @myval INT = 388

Select 
*
from newtable 
where 
/* open range */
(vmin is null and vmax is null) or 
/* no min range */
(vmin is null and @myval < vmax) or
/* no max range */
(vmin < @myval and vmax is null) or
/* lower range */
(vmin < @myval and vmax < @myval ) or
/* including range */
(@myval between vmin and vmax)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, but if you test it with 508 for example, you return only the 500 range but I need to return 400 too (nump from 1 to 5 for example)

Comment: @MCunha98 so Im sorry but if you want that, I understand that your solution is very more simple, you want all records where vmax is bigger than your value, so where vmax > variable. U can ignore vmin.

Comment: unfortunatelly I cannot ignore the vmin, for example if I use 344 as value, I need to return the range from 200 to 299 to , but ignore higher than 399

Comment: @MCunha98 sorry, I posted too fast and cant edit. By ignore vmin I mean, 344 is higher than 299 (vmax), before to be higher than 300 (next vmin). So take where (vmin < 344 AND vmax < 344) OR 344 between vmin AND vmax. First will give you range fully under 344, second part which includes your number, and 1 to 999999 cover that also without a specific case.

Comment: And I highly suggest to have a nullable vmin and vmax, to always includes records with null limits, instead of rely on 999999 number that may one day be overflowed.

Comment: Ok, I agree, use of null in this case is usefull, but, the logic continue broken

Comment: Did u tried the logic on my comment above the null comment ? I think that achieves what you want

Comment: here an example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b65312/4 , if I put nulls the problem continue because I get higher values of limit and too, I lost the previous values from value

Comment: Hi @iguypouf, after lots of tests, following your line (using null in vmin and vmax) I guess that is the best result at this moment, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b65312/36

Comment: U missed my comment above to include lower ranges ( vmin AND vmax < value ). See the update of my answer

Comment: Really I must to say thank you, for your time and effort on help me, probably the last fiddle that I shared is the best way. Using the null values, I create a trick to use for between , limited ranges and generic ranges, thanks again !